# Getting element that has specific element in it as child without jquery

Tags: javascript

I have like:

```
<li> <div id="one"></div> </li>
<li> <div id="two"></div> </li>

var d1 = document.getElementById('one');
```

I want to find li element that contains d1 without jquery, I've seen few jquery examples with child element but I can't find any without jquery.
Besides:

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i=0; i<li.lenght; i++){
   if(li[i].innerHtml == d1){
      //do something
   }
}
```

Is there a easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Try just getting the parent of the d1 element.

```js
let d1 = document.getElementById('one');
let parent = d1.parentElement;
console.log(parent)
```

```html
<li> <div id="one"></div> </li>
<li> <div id="two"></div> </li>
```